# How to remove space between \b switch and mergefield value in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have a mergefield in Word which displays a number.  I am trying to make the number display as a negative so I added a \b switch with "-".
However it now displays with a space in between the "-" and the number
Eg - 1 instead of -1
Is there a way to remove the space in between
This is my code

[image: mergefield code]

Thank you for all your help.  I am sure it is a simple answer but I have never used switches so am clueless
many thanks
Mark

Comment: Please don't display text as image.

Comment: Adding to harrymc's comment... It is much easier to troubleshoot something like this with editable text. To get your field code as text you can either select, copy and paste the field code within the braces to this forum and add the braces. Then format as code. You can also use Graham Mayor's Add-In or code to convert field codes to text. http://www.gmayor.com/export_field.htm Harrymc's answer uses this formatting. It will let you copy the field code for use in your document.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include negative formatting, add a semi-colon after the
first part.
The section after the semi colon dictates what to do with negative amounts.

Examples:

```
{MERGEFIELD AmountOwing \# "$,#.00;($,#.00)"}
{ MERGEFIELD "MktVal" \# "$,0.00;($,0.00)" }
```

For more information see
[Formatting Word fields with switches](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm).